# Grafana not picking up collectd metrics from graphite ui

Tags: graphite, grafana

I installed, graphite using pip on a system with the graphite ui, I installed collectd on the systems whose metrics I need, and everything shows up very well in the graphite ui.

I then installed grafana on a system and did an import of graphite, but in Grafana I see only, "Graphite Carbon Metrics", nothing related to collectd from the nodes presenting their metrics to graphite.

http://pastebin.com/fPZ61kwR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the collectd metrics naming convention matches what the dashboard expects.

Comment: Could you please give an example of a valid naming convention. Thanks!

Comment: Typically collectd will output metrics such as `collectd.load.load.shortterm` but if you've used a custom prefix or other naming changes it could mess up the Grafana dashboard. I believe that Torkel provides a [recommended collectd.conf](https://github.com/torkelo/dashboards/blob/master/collectd-graphite-single-server/collectd.conf) to go with the [dashboard](https://grafana.net/dashboards/24).